# Replace "state" select field first option text in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Why this code replace only my billing state default value text and not my shipping state default select value text?

```
 // Replace text in woo checkout
    function ea_custom_script_woo_checkout(){
    if(is_checkout()){
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >
            jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#billing_state option, #shipping_state option').each(function() {
                    var text = jQuery(this).text();
                    jQuery(this).text(text.replace('Seleziona un\'opzione…', 'Seleziona una provincia')); 
                })
            });
        </script>";
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'ea_custom_script_woo_checkout', 90, 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be because shipping fields are hidden at start… Please try the following:

```
// Replace state select field placeholder option text in checkout 
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_script_in_checkout', 100, 1);
function custom_script_in_checkout(){
if( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery( function($){
            function changeStateOptionText(){
                $('select[name=billing_state] option, select[name=shipping_state] option').each( function() {
                    if($(this).text() == "Seleziona un'opzione…")
                        $(this).text("Seleziona una provincia");
                });
            }
            setTimeout( changeStateOptionText, 200);

            // To be sure (if shipping fields are hidden)
            $('checkbox[name=ship_to_different_address]').change(function() {
                changeStateOptionText();
            });
        });
    </script>";
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two colections diferent and function each only iterates for one collection, could you make pull apart the collections

```
jQuery('#billing_state option').each(function() {
                var text = jQuery(this).text();
                jQuery(this).text(text.replace('Seleziona un\'opzione…',     'Seleziona una provincia')); 
jQuery('#shipping_state option').each(function() {
                var text = jQuery(this).text();
                jQuery(this).text(text.replace('Seleziona un\'opzione…',     'Seleziona una provincia')); 
            })
```

Comment: also this does not works '<script type=\"text/javascript\" >
            jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
             jQuery('#shipping_state option').each(function() {
                 var text = jQuery(this).text();
                 jQuery(this).text(text.replace('Seleziona un\'opzione…', 'Seleziona una provincia')); 
             })
         });
        </script>'

Comment: self = jQuery(this);  jQuery('#billing_state option').each(function() {
                var text = self.text();
                jQuery(this).text(text.replace('Seleziona un\'opzione…',     'Seleziona una provincia')); 
jQuery('#shipping_state option').each(function() {
                var text = self.text();
                jQuery(this).text(text.replace('Seleziona un\'opzione…',     'Seleziona una provincia')); 
            })